# Retorno inesperado en un tableView

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy realizando un proyecto universitario que trata sobre un club, intento que al registrar un nuevo miembro para el club se visualice en la tabla. He creado todo lo necesario pero al ejecutar el programa mi tabla **(sin ingresar nuevos usuarios)** retorna esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé el porqué de esos valores, recalco que para ese punto aún no he añadido nuevos miembros, por lo que idealmente la tabla debería estar vacía.

el código responsable de ese fallo es el siguiente:

```
public class ListaUsuariosController implements Initializable {
    ObservableList<Miembros> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Miembros> tablaMiembros;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrosidlista;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrosnombrelista;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrospersonajelista;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrosorigenlista;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrosactivoinactivolista;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Miembros, String> miembrosfechaingresolista;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        initColMiembros();
        loadData();
    }

    private void initColMiembros() {
        
        miembrosidlista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrosidlista"));
        miembrosnombrelista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrosnombrelista"));
        miembrospersonajelista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrospersonajelista"));
        miembrosorigenlista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrosorigenlista"));
        miembrosactivoinactivolista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrosactivoinactivolista"));
        miembrosfechaingresolista.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("miembrosfechaingresolista"));     
    }

    private void loadData() {
        list.clear(); // El clear no sé si es necesario, de igual manera, no parece afectar
        list.add(new Miembros(miembrosidlista.toString(), miembrosnombrelista.toString(), miembrospersonajelista.toString(), miembrosorigenlista.toString(), miembrosactivoinactivolista.toString(), miembrosfechaingresolista.toString()));
        tablaMiembros.setItems(list);
    }

    public static class Miembros {

        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrosidlista;
        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrosnombrelista;
        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrospersonajelista;
        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrosorigenlista;
        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrosactivoinactivolista;
        private final SimpleStringProperty miembrosfechaingresolista;

        public Miembros(String miembrosidlista, String miembrosnombrelista, String miembrospersonajelista, String miembrosorigenlista, String miembrosactivoinactivolista, String miembrosfechaingresolista) {
            this.miembrosidlista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrosidlista);
            this.miembrosnombrelista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrosnombrelista);
            this.miembrospersonajelista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrospersonajelista);
            this.miembrosorigenlista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrosorigenlista);
            this.miembrosactivoinactivolista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrosactivoinactivolista);
            this.miembrosfechaingresolista = new SimpleStringProperty(miembrosfechaingresolista);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrosidlista() {
            return miembrosidlista;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrosnombrelista() {
            return miembrosnombrelista;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrospersonajelista() {
            return miembrospersonajelista;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrosorigenlista() {
            return miembrosorigenlista;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrosactivoinactivolista() {
            return miembrosactivoinactivolista;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getMiembrosfechaingresolista() {
            return miembrosfechaingresolista;
        }
    }

}
```

Hasta los momentos sé que el problema ocurre en la función initColMiembros(), pero no sé qué realmente lo genera, asumo que son los property pero de igual manera no logro solucionarlo.

Comment: `clear()` se usa para eliminar todos los datos......

Comment: @Dramaturgo Sí, entiendo la función de eso pero no sé si en el contexto es necesario.

Comment: si quieres eliminar todos los datos que ingrese a  tu`list`  usalo,pero dentro de tu metodo `loadData()` no deberia ir

Comment: Bueno gracias por la recomendación de no colocarlo en el loadData(), la verdad solo lo vi en internet pero nunca le encontré el sentido; sin embargo ¿tienes alguna idea de cómo solucionar el problema principal? Quiero que al ejecutar el código la tabla no esté llena con esos valores que se muestran en la imagen ¿alguna idea? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en este metodo

```
private void loadData() {
    list.clear(); // El clear no sé si es necesario, de igual manera, no parece afectar
    list.add(new Miembros(miembrosidlista.toString(), miembrosnombrelista.toString(), miembrospersonajelista.toString(), miembrosorigenlista.toString(), miembrosactivoinactivolista.toString(), miembrosfechaingresolista.toString()));
    tablaMiembros.setItems(list);
}
```

list.clear() esta correcto ya que si quieres refrezcar la tabla evitaras registros duplicados.
list.add(aca debes colocar una lista de los new Miembros.)

tablaMiembros.setItems(list) esto se coloca una sola vez. ya que si la tabla extrae los datos de list. solo debes modificar posteriormente list

Te dejo un ejemplo de como inicializar un tableview

```
@FXML
private ObservableList<FormatoClientes> registros;

@FXML
private TableView<FormatoClientes> tabla;

@FXML
private TableColumn<FormatoClientes, Integer> id;

@FXML
private TableColumn<FormatoClientes, String> cliente;

@FXML
private TableColumn<FormatoClientes, String> empresa;
```

Inicializando

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        cliente.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cliente"));
        empresa.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("empresa"));
        
        registros = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tabla.setItems(registros);
        
        listaClientes = usuariosService.listar();
        
        
        this.cargaInicialTabla();
    }
```

Metodo de carga

```
private void cargaInicialTabla(){
         listaClientes.stream()
                      .filter(c -> c.getRoles().getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase("Cliente"))
                      .forEach(x -> {
                            registros.add(new FormatoClientes(x.getIdUsuarios(), x.getUsuario(), x.getProveedores().getNombreEmpresa()));
                       });
     }
```